# I can't connect with PHP CURL. I get a forbidden error

Tags: php, curl, cookies

You can use the code you want to connect to the profile and check the daily download limit. You must reach the daily limit. When I get redirected to the profile page, I get the "FORBIDDEN" warning and cannot connect. The cookie recorded by the code is also incorrect. Where am I making mistakes? The code is as follows:

```
$cookie =realpath('cookie.txt');
$cookie_1 = realpath('cookie_ORJ.txt');
define('CRF_DEGER', 'a5e67831-dd1b-4736-bcd3-7270c9cf4ec2');
define('NEXT_DEGER', '/');
define('USERNAME', 'XXXXX');
define('PASSWORD', 'XXXXX');
define('LOGIN_DEGER', 'true');
define('USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36');
define('LOGIN_FORM_URL', 'https://accounts.shutterstock.com/login?next=%2F');
define('LOGIN_ACTION_URL', 'https://accounts.shutterstock.com/login?next=%2F');

$postValues = array(
   '_csrf' => CRF_DEGER,
   'next' => NEXT_DEGER,
   'username' => USERNAME,
   'password' => PASSWORD,
   'login' => LOGIN_DEGER
);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, LOGIN_ACTION_URL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_1);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postValues));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, LOGIN_FORM_URL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);

curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));
}

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.shutterstock.com/oauth/authorize?state=98f4c4506dbeef65008c740bddb9a982&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.shutterstock.com%2Fsstk-oauth%2Fcallback%3Flanding_page%3D%252Faccount%252Fprofile%26realm%3Dcustomer&scope=licenses.create%20licenses.view%20organization.view%20purchases.view%20purchases.create%20user.edit%20user.email%20user.view%20user.address%20organization.address%20collections.view%20collections.edit%20media.upload%20media.submit%20media.edit&hl=en&client_id=4dee2-8f775-dd4c6-4e561-6e645-1aa0f');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

echo curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: If you have to forge a user agent you likely are not suppose to be doing what you're doing.

Comment: I need to access my user account and extract information from my profile. I should set the daily limit and prevent other users from exceeding the limit.